# Ktor ClientRequestException - get server message embedded in the ClientRequestException message

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I have a server that is returning a 400 response with an error message like this

```json
{ "message": "Username already exist, please try a different one.", "code": 400 }
```

and in ktor client I am setting the HTTPClient to expect true like this

```kotlin
 HttpClient {
     expectSuccess = true
 }
```

but when I try to get the exception it returns a ClientRequestException and the server message is wrapped in ClientRequestException stuff

this is the full message I get when I do `exception.message`

```
 Client request(POST http://10.0.2.2:8080/account/signup) invalid: 400 Bad Request. Text: "{ "message": "Username already exist, please try a different one.", "code": 400 }"
```

any way I can just get the server message from ClientRequestException?

Comment: You can access the `response` property of the exception to get the response object. You can then call its `body` method to receive the response body as an object: `e.response.body<ErrorResponse>()` (https://ktor.io/docs/response.html).

Comment: bleh! I refactored my code to just avoid this haha. Oh well I'm sure it'll come in handy eventually. Thanks!

Comment: You can set this as an answer and I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `response` property of the `ClientRequestException` to get the response object. You can then call its `body` method to receive the deserialized response body as an object: `e.response.body<ErrorResponse>()`. Please refer to the [official documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/response.html) to learn about handling responses.